# Whats the best practice for creating and sending an email attachment using Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, rails-api

I need to know if I'm implementing the correct  procedure  when sending an email with an attached .xls document.
The attached .xls document would simple have the information provided in an object.  ...ie: person.first_name  person.last_name.  The xls file will render the full names of the list.

I have a front-end React.js with a back-end Rails API.

I actually have it working in it’s most simple way but I’m not sure if this would be the best way.

Please let me know if there is amore efficient way of doing this.

Currently I have this setup: In my React Action Creator I have a fetch calling to a custom “list” method on my  controller backend.  In this controller I’m creating and writing the file like this:

```
File.open(“new_file”, 'w+') do | f |
     c = @list.names  do | name, data |
    f.puts ( "#{name.first_name}  #{name.last_name}")
    f.close
 end
end
```

The above code will create a file in the root of my application which I’m not sure if it’s best practice.

After this code runs the mailer sends out the email with the proper xls file attached .

**My question is:**  What do I do with this newly created file on the root of my rails application.  Is this normal to have and every time this runs the file is overwritten which is okay in my opinion.  What if two different people on different devices run the code at the same time.  Will there be a chance of the list being mixed up and one user getting the wrong list?  **I just feel like this is not right to create a  file to my back-end Rails api whenever my user needs a list emailed to them.** Even if I delete it right after it’s  sent in the mailer.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating temporally files with the ruby [API](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html)

Or if there is not a need to reuse the file use [send_data](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data)

If you have thousand of files that need caching is worth thinking something like the official [Rails cache api](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html)(you can cache any kind of file no just HTML )

Comment: Thank you osdamv!  I will check this out and see if i can get it working.